# Dynamically loading assemblies and instantiating types using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, abstract-class

I have a requirement to dynamically load and cast an instance of a class to it's various base types using requirement. Now on reading and trying my hand on some examples, I find that either I probably don't understand all that I need to when it comes to working with classes at runtime.

I have a situation where  Abstract class B implements interface A. Now Class B is a base class for class C. When I dynamically load, at runtime, the assembly that contains all 3 types, I expect that I should be able to, using Load From context, load the assembly, create an instance of class C, and cast it to type of interface A. But that does not seem to be happening at all and I would appreciate an explanation as to why. Thanks in Advance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xkww633.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx

```
public interface ICaseOutputGenerator
{
    String SampleProperty { get; set; }
    void Process();

}

public abstract class CaseOutputGeneratorBase : ICaseOutputGenerator
{
    public String SecondSampleProperty { get; set; }


    public virtual void SecondProcessMethod()
    {
    }

    public abstract void ThirdSampleProcessMethod();


    public string SampleProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process in CaseOutputGeneratorBase Called");
    }
}

public class TestCaseOutputGenerator : CaseOutputGeneratorBase
{
    public override void ThirdSampleProcessMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

public class TestSandBoxManager
    {

```
    public TestSandBoxManager()
    {


    }

    public String ProcessAssemblyByFullDisplayName(String assemblyFullDisplayName)
    {
        String temp = String.Empty;
        var casecust = GetAssemblyByFullDisplayName(assemblyFullDisplayName);
        if (casecust != null)
            temp = ("Cast Passed");
        else
            temp = ("Cast Failed");

        return temp;

    }


    public String ProcessFile(String assemblyName, String className)
    {
        String temp = String.Empty;
        var casecust = GetCaseOutputGeneratorObject(assemblyName, className);
        if (casecust != null)
            temp=("Cast Passed");
        else
            temp=("Cast Failed");

        return temp;

    }

    private static object GetAssemblyByFullDisplayName(string fullName)
    {
        try
        {
            Type caseOutputGen = null;
            String fullQualifiedName = String.Empty;
            var localAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullName);

            foreach (var testType in localAssembly.GetTypes())
            {

                if ( testType.FullName != fullName)
                    continue; 
                fullQualifiedName = testType.FullName;
                break;
            }
            if (fullQualifiedName == null)
                return null;

            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(fullQualifiedName));
            return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }



    public String ProcessFile2(String assemblyName, String className)
    {
        String temp = String.Empty;
        var casecust = GetCaseOutputGeneratorObjectLoadFrom(assemblyName, className);
        if (casecust != null)
            temp = ("Cast Passed");
        else
            temp = ("Cast Failed");

        return temp;

    }

    public static ICaseOutputGenerator GetCaseOutputGeneratorObject(string assemblyName, string className)
    {
        ICaseOutputGenerator caseOutputGen = null;

        var obj = GetObject(assemblyName, className);
        if (obj != null)
            caseOutputGen = (ICaseOutputGenerator)obj; // FAILS HERE
        return caseOutputGen;
    }

    public static ICaseOutputGenerator GetCaseOutputGeneratorObjectLoadFrom(string assemblyName, string className)
    {
        ICaseOutputGenerator caseOutputGen = null;

        try
        {
            var obj = GetObject2(assemblyName, className);
            if (obj != null)
                caseOutputGen = (ICaseOutputGenerator)obj; // FAILS HERE
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            throw ex;
        }
        return caseOutputGen; 
    }

    private static object GetObject2(string fullName, string className)
    {
        try
        {
            Type caseOutputGen = null;
            String fullQualifiedName = String.Empty;
            var localAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullName);

            foreach (var testType in localAssembly.GetTypes())
            {

                if (!testType.FullName.EndsWith(className, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
                continue;
                caseOutputGen = testType;
                fullQualifiedName = testType.FullName;
                break;
            }
            if (caseOutputGen == null) 
                return null;

            var obj = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(fullName, fullQualifiedName);
            return obj.Unwrap();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }


    private static object GetObject(string fullName, string className)
    {
        try
        {
            Type caseOutputGen = null;
            var localAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullName);
            foreach (var testType in localAssembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (!testType.FullName.EndsWith(className, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) continue;
                caseOutputGen = testType;
                break;
            }
            if (caseOutputGen == null) return null;

            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(caseOutputGen);
            return obj;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load assembly: " + Environment.NewLine + fullName, ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load assembly: " + Environment.NewLine + fullName, ex);
        }
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public Boolean testReflection2()
    {
        try
        {
            //create an instance of the testsandboxmanager
            TestSandBoxManager t = new TestSandBoxManager();
            String ret = t.ProcessFile2(@"...\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TestSandBox\TestSandBox\bin\Debug\TestSandBox.dll", "TestCaseOutputGenerator");
            Console.WriteLine(ret);
            Console.ReadLine();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

[image: IMage of my solution to help those who understand the question so far]

Comment: "FAILS HERE" is a bit too abstract, please supply more details. What fails? How are you even referring to `ICaseOutputGenerator` from the main assembly if it's in your dynamically loadable assembly?

Comment: This is no multiple question. If you read well, the one is about figuring out how to test without needing to add the assembly to the test project. This question is about understanding Reflection itself and how it works.

Comment: @ Anton Tykhyy, what more details do you want? You have the code there to test if you doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have 2 `ICaseOutputGenerator` - one in each assembly. You can't cast object/interface to similarly named interface in another assembly even if code is identical. You can check the fact that create object implements `ICaseOutputGenerator` from its own assembly by looking at created object in the debugger.

If it is the case you need to figure out where you want to put `ICaseOutputGenerator` interface so it is coming from the same assembly for both "custom loaded assembly" and you main application. Often shared interfaces are implemented in separate assembly and linked to all "plug-in" assemblies as well as application assembly.

Comment: There is definitely just the copy of ICaseOutputGenerator there. Also, if there were more than one wouldn't the exception message be different there.

Comment: @Kobojunkie - there no exception information in your post and no information on in what assembly each class is located... so it is unclear what "wouldn't the exception message be different" relates to as there is no message to start with. I'd recommend to step through the code and look at each object in the debugger to see if you can solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I posted all the code there. Please copy and try to run it as I explained to understand the question being asked. I do get an invalidcast exception that I cannot cast TestCaseOutputGenerator  to ICaseOutputGenerator type. Again, if you tried the code, you would at least get a better understanding of the question being asked please.

Comment: @Kobojunkie your code is impossible to run because it is incomplete. There are methods defined outside of classes (GetCaseOutputGeneratorObjectLoadFrom, GetObject2, testReflection2) and there is type that you did not give the definition of (TestSandBoxManager). The code as you presented it won't compile or run. That makes it difficult to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited to include all of TestSandBoxManager there

Answer (score 1):

I think that Alexei Levenkov is spot on. You load your TestSandBox.dll twice. Once as a reference to your project and second time via Assembly.LoadFrom. As per [documentation that you yourself linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) this can result in unexpected behaviour. Here is a quote for you reference:

> If an assembly is loaded with LoadFrom, and the probing path includes
>   an assembly with the same identity but a different location, an
>   InvalidCastException, MissingMethodException, or other unexpected
>   behavior can occur.

This is exactly what's happening in your case. If you change the path you are loading your assembly from to point to the same folder as your main executable, it will work fine.

Comment: What path is my main executable loading my assembly from? That is part of what I am trying to figure out here. I have an image of the references up there. Where do I point it to? TestSandbox? TestSandBoxMock? TestSandBoxService? Or TestSandboxService.Test? Which?

Comment: As I say in the answer above most likely it's it the same folder as your main executable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Also a sound advice, is when you have a limited number of easily testable answers is to test them all and see which works. I takes about 15 seconds to paste a new path into the source code recompile and hit the run button.